# git grep output is buffered. Why?

Tags: git

I run `git grep` for the first time on a large tree (the Linux kernel).

This takes a long time to run.  If I cancel with ctrl+C before it finishes, often it immediately shows a line it found.

Why did `git grep` not show the line immediately, when it found it?

---

```
$ rpm -q git
git-2.17.2-1.fc28.x86_64
```

Comment: Yeah, I think it defaults sending the output to less if I am not wrong.

Comment: By default the output is piped to $GIT_PAGER, or the value of the core.pager config, or $PAGER, or a value chosen at compile time (usually `less`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git grep` output is buffered by `less`.  (In most cases.  It can be changed using various configuration options, if you need to).

The reason I did not notice this, is that `git grep` does not show the `less` pager footer when there is less than one screen of output.  However, the output is still buffered.  (I can see that `less` is running, by opening another terminal and running `ps -ax`).

Comment: you can disable it `alias agit='git --no-pager'` http://github.com/cup/bay/blob/7b10c7b/core/bash/.profile#L18

Answer (score 2):

In reality, checking sources, git output is not buffered by less all the time.

Checking pager.c, it shows git output is buffered by the program pointed to the PAGER shell variable; if it is not defined, less will be used by omission.

More interestingly yet, while the less output is being paged, it sets the shell GIT_PAGER_IN_USE variable to true. When invoking the pager, it checks for that variable.

As an oddity, it seems it does not like `cat` as a pager, if it detects it, it blanks it out.

```
#ifndef DEFAULT_PAGER
#define DEFAULT_PAGER "less"
#endif
....

void setup_pager(void)
{
    const char *pager = git_pager(isatty(1));

    if (!pager)
        return;

    /*
     * After we redirect standard output, we won't be able to use an ioctl
     * to get the terminal size. Let's grab it now, and then set $COLUMNS
     * to communicate it to any sub-processes.
     */
    {
        char buf[64];
        xsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", term_columns());
        setenv("COLUMNS", buf, 0);
    }

    setenv("GIT_PAGER_IN_USE", "true", 1);

    /* spawn the pager */
    prepare_pager_args(&pager_process, pager);
    pager_process.in = -1;
    argv_array_push(&pager_process.env_array, "GIT_PAGER_IN_USE");
    if (start_command(&pager_process))
        return;

    /* original process continues, but writes to the pipe */
    dup2(pager_process.in, 1);
    if (isatty(2))
        dup2(pager_process.in, 2);
    close(pager_process.in);

    /* this makes sure that the parent terminates after the pager */
    sigchain_push_common(wait_for_pager_signal);
    atexit(wait_for_pager_atexit);
}
```